# Prove the injectivity of a function with two variables and sketch it

Tags: calculus

How can I prove that $f(x,y) = (e^x \cos y, e^x \sin y)$ is injective in $A = \{(x,y) \in R^2 | 0 < y < 2\pi\}$? I know that proving the injectivity is done by proving $f(x, y) = f(z, w) \Rightarrow x = z$ and $y = w$, but I don't know how to continue after making the system.

After that, how can I have a notion of how to sketch this function?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** note that $\|f(x,y)\|_2=|e^x|=e^x$, so $f(x,y)=f(z,w)$ imply that $e^x=e^z$, what can just happen when $x=z$, thus we had reduced the exercise to prove that if $y\neq w$ then $f(x,y)\neq f(x,w)$.

Now use what you knows about the sine and cosine to finish. That is, if $\cos y=\cos w$ then show that necessarily $\sin y\neq \sin w$.